# Nginx server : upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed)

Tags: php, mysql, nginx

We are running a service which will migrate the issues from Jira to test link.So I am using nginx server to communicate with mysql database and to run the testlink in the browser.

when I import more no of issue suddenly the nginx server get closed automatically.I am running my service and nginx server in Windows server 2008 R2 standard and 64 bit OS.
I checked the error.log file in the `C:\nginx\logs` and found the error as

> upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 192.168.27.151, server: localhost, request: "GET /testlink/lib/general/frmWorkArea.php?feature=reqSpecMgmt HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "wo-qatestlink01", referrer: "http://wo-qatestlink01/testlink/lib/general/navBar.php?tproject_id=0&tplan_id=0&updateMainPage=1"

Thanks.

**Log File**

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    proxy_read_timeout 600; 

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index index.php;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
            #The above line has been added and below line has been commented to use the php code.
            #index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #   proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        ########## Code added during Configuration By Anthony ################
        location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  c:/nginx/html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        }
        ######################################################################
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: cleaned up formatting

Comment: You would need to supply more info, like nginx.conf contents, what is running on port 9000 and with which parameters is your fcgi started, how long does it take for your upstream to process a generic request...

Comment: Check time(out) values like client_body_timeout, client_header_timeout, keepalive_timeout, send_timeout,   keepalive_requests.

And the values in conf/fastcgi_params.

"because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time".

How long before this timeout happens?

Answer (score 2):

This issue is due to nginx timing out before it gets a response from the backend (php). There are a few timeouts that be set in nginx to change this.

The default "response" timeout from fastcgi is 60s. You have it at 600s, which might not be enough time.

```
fastcgi_read_timeout 60s;
```

[Nginx Documentation : FastCGI Module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_read_timeout)

Answer (score 1):

in my case, I was running my Server inside a FreeBSD Jail (**Nginx 1.6.2, PHP/5.6.6**) using TCP-Port instead of socket. The problem resolved changing two settings in my

> php-fpm.conf

file:

```
;listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1 # comment out to listen to any
listen = 9000 # No IP-Address
```

It worked.